# mouse click not working on google recaptcha checkbox part of form

Tags: javascript, forms, recaptcha

I have a issue with a form that has v2 checkbox for I'm not a robot, the mouse clicks don't seem to be working any more when trying to check the I'm not a robot checkbox, I can tab to it and press the enter key and it works but the google recaptcha checkbox is not detecting the mouse click any more for some reason. It's a new issue on me, has anyone else had this issue and how can I solve it as I don't understand this issue as was working all ok up until now

Thank you in advance, I can provide code but as am unsure what the issue is, I didn't want to post a lot of code that was not needed to post, below is the code I have

```
<?php 
$postData = $statusMsg = ''; 
$status = 'error'; 

// If the form is submitted 
if(isset($_POST['submitfooterform'])){ 
$postData = $_POST; 
 
// Validate form fields 
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && 
!empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
     
    // Validate reCAPTCHA box 
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g- 
    recaptcha-response'])){
        // Google reCAPTCHA API secret key 
        $secretKey = '';
         
        // Verify the reCAPTCHA response 
        $verifyResponse = 
      
     file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); 
         
        // Decode json data 
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse); 
         
        // If reCAPTCHA response is valid 
        if($responseData->success){ 
            // Posted form data 
            $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
            $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
            $phone = !empty($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:'';
            $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';
             
            // Send email notification to the site admin 
            $to = ''; 
            $subject = 'New Website Enquiry'; 
            $htmlContent = " 
                <h3>Contact Form Details</h3>
                <br><br>
                <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
                <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
                <p><b>Phone: </b>".$phone."</p>
                <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p>
            "; 
             
            // Always set content-type when sending HTML email 
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
            // More headers 
            $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' ' . "\r\n";
             
            // Send email 
            @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers); 
             
            $status = 'success'; 
            $statusMsg = header("Location: ../enquiry-confirmation.php");
            $postData = '';
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = "<strong>" . 'Robot verification failed, please try again.' . "</strong>"; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $statusMsg = "<strong>" . 'Please check on the reCAPTCHA box.' . "</strong>";
    } 
}else{ 
    $statusMsg = 'Please fill all the mandatory fields.'; 
} 
} 
?>

<form class="needs-validation" action="includes/footer.php" method="post" name="contact-form">
                            <div class="form-row">
                            
                           <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required name="name" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['name'])?$postData['name']:''; ?>">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required name="email" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['email'])?$postData['email']:''; ?>">
                                </div>
                                
                                <br><br>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['phone'])?$postData['phone']:''; ?>">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12 Textarea-btn">
                                        <textarea class="form-control mb-3" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" placeholder="Your message..." name="message" required><?php echo !empty($postData['message'])?$postData['message']:''; ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallbackftr" data-sitekey=""></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12 Textarea-btn">
                                <button id="submitBtnftr" class="btn btn-dark btn-dark-animated" type="submit" name="submitfooterform" disabled>Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                                
                                </div><!-- Form Row /-->
                            </form>
```

Comment: Maybe you have some visual/transparent element ahead blocking the click ?  Can we see your code ?

Comment: I thought that as well and something overlapping it but can't see anything when checked inspect element in firefox. I have added the form code above

Comment: Think I just sorted it, it was caused by pointer-events: none; in my css stylesheet for iframe. Is odd that it has been working all ok up until that point but least it's sorted now